# The table header is displaying as many times as JSON data. How can I fix that

Tags: reactjs, jsx

In my below code, I want to name the first row as "CompanyName" and so on. But instead the table name is rendering as many times as total values in JSON. Could anyone tell me how I can resolve the error and display the column names on the first row an then the data.

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import { stockData } from "./data";


  export const Stocks = () => {
    return (
      <>
        <HomePageHeader />
        <div className="stock-container">
          {stockData.map((data, key) => {
            return (
              <div key={key}>
                <Stock
                  key={key}
                  company={data.company}
                  ticker={data.ticker}
                  stockPrice={data.stockPrice}
                  timeElapsed={data.timeElapsed}
                />
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      </>
    );
  };
  const HomePageHeader=()=>{
    return(
      <header className="header">
        Your stock tracker
      </header>
    );
  };


  const Stock = ({ company, ticker, stockPrice, timeElapsed }) => {
    if (!company) return <div />;
    return (
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <h5>Company Name</h5>
            </td>
            
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    );
  };
```

Comment: do you want to render table so headers are fixed and table body is the data in stockData object?

Comment: yea, can you help me with that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to render a table with fixed headers and dynamic data, here is an example:

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import { stockData } from "./data";

export const Stocks = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <HomePageHeader />
      <StockTable />  
    </>
  );
};

const HomePageHeader=()=>{
  return(
    <header className="header">
      Your stock tracker
    </header>
  );
};


const StockTable = ({ company, ticker, stockPrice, timeElapsed }) => {
  if (!company) return <div />;
  return (
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <h5>Company Name</h5>
            <h5>Ticker</h5>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {stockData.map((data, key) => {
          return (
            <tr>
              <td>{data.company}</td>
              <td>{data.ticker}</td>
            </tr>
          );
        })}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
};
```

Comment: I tried the mentioned method but they are displaying on the same row. Can you tell how I can make sure they display in new rows

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are creating a new table for each stock while you should create the table once and then add rows. Here is an example that should work for you following the namings you already provided:

```
export default function App() {
  let stocks = null;
  if (stockData.length) {
    stocks = (
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Company</th>
            <th>Ticker</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Elapsed Time</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {stockData.map((stock, x) => (
            <Stock
              key={stock.company}
              company={stock.company}
              ticker={stock.ticker}
              stockPrice={stock.stockPrice}
              timeElapsed={stock.timeElapsed}
            />
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    );
  }

  return (
    <>
      <HomePageHeader />
      <div className="stock-container">{stocks}</div>
    </>
  );
}

const HomePageHeader = () => {
  return <header className="header">Your stock tracker</header>;
};

const Stock = ({ company, ticker, stockPrice, timeElapsed }) => {
  if (!company) return;
  return (
    <tr>
      <td>{company}</td>
      <td>{ticker}</td>
      <td>{stockPrice}</td>
      <td>{timeElapsed}</td>
    </tr>
  );
};
```